# About reversal from "Thu, July 23" to "July 23, Thu"

Tags: dates

My app needs to display dates in a shortened form.

Each dates needs to include the day of the week as well, but I want to put more focus on the date itself. So, I'm considering a reverted version of dates, as shown below:

- This year: `Jul 23, Thu`
- Another year: `7/23/19, Thu`

I put the day of the week to the end because it is just extra information and the date itself much more matters.

But, because this is not a typical date format in English, I'm worried that users might feel confused.

How do you think? Is this inversion acceptable? Or should I strictly follow the standard English date format?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Parentheses**

"July 23 (Thu)" is acceptable to English speakers and preserves the desired order. Something similar will work in most (perhaps all?) languages, if localization is a concern.

**Option 2: Tooltip on hover**

Another, slightly more involved, alternative is to offer more info about the date with a tooltip on hover. This is quite a common pattern for dates. The existence of the tooltip could be indicated with a dotted underline under the base text.

For example, the base text could be "July 23", with a tooltip showing "Thursday, July 23, 2020".

If it's a web app, however, note that `title` attributes aren't available on touchscreen devices, so you'd probably want to use a proper tooltip library instead.